# iOS Subscription - Do I need server?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Lets say I have an app that needs an active subscription to access features.The subscription should auto-renew each month. Once the subscription is activated via in-app purchase is that all? Or do I have to do the whole receipt verification via server thing?

So:

1) Do I need a server store? If so why?

2) How do I cancel a subscription if the user requests it?

I'm going off of this link: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/RenewableSubscriptions/RenewableSubscriptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH4-SW2

But it seems like a lot more work than should be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. But the good news is that it doesn't have to be yours.

There are a handful of good thrid-party web services that can provide this infrastructure for you. Urban Airship is one that I have used in the past, but look around and compare features and costs.

See: http://urbanairship.com/products/in-app-purchase/

Comment: Urban Airship are discontinuing IAP.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do a receipt verification, but it is recommended. Receipt verification is only there to verify that the purchase is valid (could be corrupted by pirates for example).

The user will be able to cancel the subscriptions in the settings, you don't need to do it yourself.