# how to use the iphone auto renew subscription without a server

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

So all the documentation and posts I see about auto-renew subscription are using the [server side](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/APIOverview/OverviewoftheStoreKitAPI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH100-SW1) model to deliver products. Is there a particular reason why one couldn't use the Built-in model.

I am creating a audio player app that will provide new original music every month. With service side verification I understand that it checks to see if the receipt is valid before allowing the user to download the audios from my server.

However, couldn't I just program my app to ping the app store to see if their subscription is active. If their subscription isn't active have the app sit on the home screen saying "Please renew your subscription before regaining access to the audio player"

It's my understanding that the server side model is there to [prevent pirates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9297913/1594491) from gaining access to my servers resources. Is there any other reason I should use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on whether you want your application to be hacked or not.
Main reason for all the validation routine is that once application is available to user, he can modify it in any way he likes which can be seen on all the hacked iPhone apps out there. 
So in your case they would delete all checks from your code and set "active" to true.

Comment: In what way the server-side model would prevent that to happen ?

Comment: @Haelty well of course. If it's the backend that desides whether user is allowed to get new content or not, no user can hack or change this system. Take Diablo 3 for example - it wasn't hacked and it can't be, because all monsters locations & loot on the map is stored on the server. And server knows whether you payed for your game or not.